# How to display when $RANDOM = $$

Tags: bash

Just for fun I wanted to count the number of times it takes for `$RANDOM` to equal `$$`.

```
i=1
while [[ $RANDOM != $$ ]]
do
    echo -e "$(( i++ ))\t$RANDOM\t$$"
done
```

I wanted to also display the count `$i` when `$RANDOM` finally does equal `$$`. So I tried adding this to the end of the script.

```
if [[ $RANDOM = $$ ]]; then
    echo -e "$RANDOM\t$$"
fi
```

But this doesn't work. How can I display the final count when `$RANDOM = $$`?

Comment: `$RANDOM` will give you a new value each time you use it. If you want to both test it and print it you'll have to save the value somewhere.

Comment: But if I save the value of `$RANDOM` won't that be same value every time?

Comment: @I0_ol You'd have to ‘re-save’ it to get new values, of course.

Comment: Ok I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: @I0_ol `a=$RANDOM` will give `$a` a random value. `a=$RANDOM` again will give it a new random value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I tried adding this to the end of the script.

That *another* value of `$RANDOM`. When the loop breaks, you *know* `$$` is the value that the last `$RANDOM` had. So, you might as well use the `$$`.

If you *really* need to verify that, then store the `$RANDOM` in a temporary variable in each iteration and use that temp variable when the loop breaks.